# Django form not passing value to cleaned_data

Tags: django, django-forms

I have this view:

```
def new_booking(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookingForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        print "form before clean: %s" % form.data  # Data is here
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
```

and this form:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def clean(self):
        print "form data in clean method: %s" % self.cleaned_data
        hora = self.cleaned_data['hora']  # !!! KeyError
        print hora

    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['hora', 'nombre', 'email', 'archivo']
        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'archivo': forms.FileInput(attrs={}),
            'hora': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control date', 'id': 'booking_time', 'readonly': 'readonly'})
        }
```

So.. the first print (the one in the view) gives me this:

```
form before clean: <QueryDict: {u'hora': [u'Jueves 4 de Febrero a las 9:00 am '], u'nombre': [u'Alejandro'], u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': [u'**********'], u'email': [u'alejo@gmail.com']}>
```

The second print, the one in the `clean` method, gives me this:

```
form data in clean method: {'nombre': u'Alejandro', 'email': u'alejo@gmail.com', 'archivo': <InMemoryUploadedFile: SO_username_admin_upZnsyk.png (image/png)>}
```

As you can see, for some reason I don't understand, the `hora` kwarg has disappeared from the data dict: It doesn't show up in `self.cleaned_data`.

Extra info: I need to manipulate it in the `clean` method cause I'm receiving a string I need to coerce into a datetime. But, why isn't it there?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the base class clean method first to get the cleaned_data:

```
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(BookingForm, self).clean()
    print "form data in clean method: %s" % cleaned_data
    hora = self.cleaned_data['hora']
    print hora
```

Django [doc example of clean method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other).

Comment: Ok its true I was missing the call to `super`, thanks. But If I change that, I still dont' get the "hora" field in the cleaned_data dict.

Comment: What field type it is for your field `hora`?

Comment: I just changed it from `TimeInput` to `TextInput`

Comment: I'm not talking about the widget, i'm talking about the field type in your model.

Comment: Ok, in my model I have a `DateTimeField`.  ... but I thought the cleaning could be overriden... I mean, it could taken care of in the `clean` method.

Comment: Well, if you feed the `DateTimeField` with `'Jueves 4 de Febrero a las 9:00 am '`, then apparently it's not going to work.

Comment: Django would be doing the validation for individual field first before reaching `clean` method, so if the data is already invalid, it won't made into `cleaned_data`.

Comment: If you want to do custom validation of the field, you should create a method called [`clean_hora()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) inside the form class.

Answer (score 1):

You declare 'hora' in your form as a `TimeInput`, but the value you receive in `request.POST` is a string that not only contains the time, but also the date. For that reason, the value is invalid and 'hora' is not set in `form.cleaned_data` when the `clean()` method is called. I guess `form.is_valid()` returns false.

Comment: It does return false. I understand what you are saying, but why wouldn't it be there? I thought the `clean` method received the complete dict.. and then called `to_python` to coerce the values into python. I want to edit the form somewhere so I can manually convert the string into a `datetime`.

Comment: Ok I changed the `TimeInput` to a `TextInput` ... and still get the same error.

Comment: `clean()` validates that the received value matches the field restrictions, so if you pase a datetime string to a time field, the validation fails. If you need a whole datetime, I'd suggest to declare 'hora' as a forms.DateTimeField: https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#datetimefield

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the solution was to declare the field explicitly:

```
class BookingForm(forms.ModelForm):

    hora = forms.CharField(max_length=150, required=True,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control date', 'id': 'booking_time', 'readonly': 'readonly'}))  #HERE


    def clean_hora(self):            

        hora = self.cleaned_data['hora']

        return process_time_string(hora)


    class Meta:
        model = Booking
        fields = ['hora', 'nombre', 'email', 'archivo']
        widgets = {
            'nombre': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'archivo': forms.FileInput(attrs={}),
            'hora': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control date', 'id': 'booking_time', 'readonly': 'readonly'})
        }
```

Then, I can receive the data in `self.cleaned_data['hora']` and process it in the function `clean_hora` as @LostMyGlasses suggested. The function `process_time_string` just gets the string, calls `strptime` and returns a datetime.